# how tid values are set in timeml Specification Language?

Tags: temporal, temporal-database, sutime, timex

In timeml Specification Language there is a value for every timex tag named `tid`. like:

```
bad financial <TIMEX3 tid="t83" type="DURATION" value="P1W">week</TIMEX3> for Asia
```

how they should initialized at starting of a text. Do `tid` tags follow any pattern?

there is no explanation about this in it's [Official Site](http://www.timeml.org/publications/timeMLdocs/timeml_1.2.1.html).

the starting value matters because when evaluating a system against [TimeBank](http://www.timeml.org/timebank/timebank.html) , the official script uses those `tid` for making an evaluation.

UPDATE:
I use Evaluation Toolkit introduced in [here](http://cs.york.ac.uk/semeval-2013/task1/index.php%3Fid=data.html) and TimeBank data set i mentioned above . `tid` that my code is generating starts with 1 but in TimeBank it starts in different numbers like 218, i cant undrestand it's numbering logic.how can i evaluate output when `tid`s are different.

Answer (score 1):

According to timeml guidelines: http://www.timeml.org/tempeval2/tempeval2-trial/guidelines/timex3guidelines-072009.pdf:

> The attribute tid [..] is automatically
>   assigned by the annotation tool.

So the evaluation you're talking about is done by custom calculation.

Do you want to share some evaluation examples, in order to see if they share some kind of logic that you can work on?